# How to setup StartupUri in App.xaml, if the startup window is in a different project/library?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view, startup

Below is my solution tree, where you can see, that `App.xaml` is in **G_Hoover.Init** project, and `BrowserView.xaml` window is in **G_Hoover.Views** project.

[image: solution tree]

I am trying to figure out how to define `StartupUri` in `App.xaml`, that `BrowserView.xaml` will be a startup window.

Only approach I found [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065646/8532173), but when I type in `App.xaml`:

```
StartupUri="C:/Users/asus/Desktop/IT/Programowanie/Projekty/G_Hoover/G_Hoover.Views/BrowserView.xaml"
```

I receive an exception:

> XamlObjectWriterException: Specified class name
>   'G_Hoover.Views.BrowserView' doesn't match actual root instance type
>   'System.Windows.Window'. Remove the Class directive or provide an
>   instance via XamlObjectWriterSettings.RootObjectInstance.

When I type:

```
StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/G_Hoover;G_Hoover.Views/BrowserView.xaml">
```

I receive exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource
>   'g_hoover;g_hoover.views/browserview.xaml'.'

And the same results I have when I type it in `App.xaml.cs` basing on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606084/8532173):

```
public partial class App : Application

{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        StartupUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";G_Hoover.Views/BrowserView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //or this: StartupUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/G_Hoover;G_Hoover.Views/BrowserView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //or this: StartupUri = new Uri("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/IT/Programowanie/Projekty/G_Hoover/G_Hoover.Views/BrowserView.xaml");
    }
}
```

Please note that **G_Hoover.Init** has reference to **G_Hoover.Views**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `StartupUri` from `App.xaml` and manage app startup in `App.xaml.cs`.

For example:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var startupView = new G_Hoover.Views.BrowserView.xaml();
        startupView.ShowDialog();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it worked and was more simple than I expected to be. Thank you.